# Output directory for maven-bundle-plugin

Tags: maven, bundle, pom.xml

I have this POM file which generates osgi bundle:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>test</groupId>
    <artifactId>test</artifactId>
    <name>test</name>
    <description>Module test</description>
    <packaging>bundle</packaging>
    <version>4.0</version>
    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>junit</groupId>
                <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
                <version>4.11</version>
                <scope>test</scope>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.apache.felix</groupId>
                <artifactId>org.osgi.core</artifactId>
                <version>1.4.0</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.osgi</groupId>
                <artifactId>org.osgi.compendium</artifactId>
                <version>5.0.0</version>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.felix</groupId>
            <artifactId>org.osgi.core</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax</groupId>
            <artifactId>javaee-web-api</artifactId>
            <version>7.0</version>
            <type>jar</type>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.felix</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-bundle-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.4.0</version>
                <extensions>true</extensions>
                <configuration>
                    <instructions>
                        <Import-Package>*</Import-Package>
                        <Bundle-SymbolicName>${project.artifactId}</Bundle-SymbolicName>
                    </instructions>
                    <outputDirectory>${user.home}/bbbblx</outputDirectory>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.8</source>
                    <target>1.8</target>
                    <encoding>${project.build.sourceEncoding}</encoding>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.6</version>
                <configuration>
                    <encoding>${project.build.sourceEncoding}</encoding>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    </properties>
</project>
```

For some reason I cannot configure the plugin to generate the output bundle into the `<outputDirectory>${user.home}/bbbblx</outputDirectory>` directory.
There is no bbbblx directory in my home directory.

Can you help me to fix this issue?

Answer (score 1):

You should use `<buildDirectory>${user.home}/bbbblx</buildDirectory>` instead of `<outputDirectory>${user.home}/bbbblx</outputDirectory>`.

I had the same problem and the fix mentioned above did the trick for me!